# Asking to install JDK for Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a simple PDF to excel conversion using `pyPDF2` and `tabula` (using Mac w/ Catalina 10.15.1):

```
import PyPDF2
import tabula
pdf = open('pdf','rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
tabulaPDF = tabula.read_pdf("pdf")
tabula.convert_into("pdf","pdf.xlsx",output_format="xlsx")
```

Whenever I run this code, I get the same error:

```
To use the java command line tool you need to install a JDK.
```

I have the newest version of java already installed, and I was told by Apple support that Catalina doesn't support the legacy Java 6 that the Java website recommends using when encountering this error. Is there some sort of workaround or solution?

Comment: how exactly are you running the code ?, try running it using the terminal, using python <filename>

Comment: Which line of code produces the error?

Comment: Do you have the JRE or JDK installed?

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 installation on Catalina answered in [legacy Java Runtime 6 Catilina Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59023621/legacy-java-runtime-6-catilina-mac)
I was able to install the legacy version on top of Java 13.0.1