# Aptana 3 error on Catalina - legacy Java Runtime 6 required

Tags: java, macos, aptana, macos-catalina

I installed Aptana Studio 3 on my MAC which I updated to the Newest OS Catalina. That is what outdated all my adobe applications and Dreamweaver was a favourite program. Installing Aptana Studio 3 I can't open it because it says I need to instal Legacy Java SE Runtime 6. But I can't install that because Catalina has a higher version of Java that is already installed. So I can't open Aptana Studio 3.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this more likely to https://superuser.com/ ?

Comment: In short, Java 6 is 32-bit and cannot be run on Catalina. Ask the developers of Aptana what to do.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4):

Steps to install Java 6 on Catalina

From https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/Self-Help-Tools/Help-Articles/Help-Articles-Detail/ArtMID/10220/ArticleID/23780/Mac-OS-Catalina-1015-ENVIIDL-and-Legacy-Java-6-Dependencies)

1. Open Finder
2. Navigate to Applications > Utilities > Script Editor
3. Select "New Document" button
4. Copy the following text to the Script Editor Document:

   ```
   set theDMG to choose file with prompt "Please select javaforosx.dmg:" of type {"dmg"}
   do shell script "hdiutil mount " & quoted form of POSIX path of theDMG
   do shell script "pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Java\\ for\\ macOS\\ 2017-001/JavaForOSX.pkg ~/tmp"
   do shell script "hdiutil unmount /Volumes/Java\\ for\\ macOS\\ 2017-001/"
   do shell script "sed -i '' 's/return false/return true/g' ~/tmp/Distribution"
   do shell script "pkgutil --flatten ~/tmp ~/Desktop/ModifiedJava6Install.pkg"
   do shell script "rm -rf ~/tmp"
   display dialog "Modified ModifiedJava6Install.pkg saved on desktop" buttons {"Ok"}
   ```
5. Select Script > Compile from the menu, or select the "Hammer" button to ensure the above copy and pasted code compiles.
6. Select Script > Run from the menu, or select the "Arrow" run button.
7. Running the script will create a ModifiedJava6Install.pkg on your desktop. Run this ModifiedJava6Install.pkg to install Java 6.

This should work to enable adding legacy Java onto the Catalina Mac OS device

Comment: The script made no difference for me on Mojave 10.14.6. I get this error after installing with the modified pkg via script.

"Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.8 or greater is required."

Comment: It doesn't create any file in my case

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:
Get `JavaForOSX.dmg` file from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US
Run below 7-commands in Terminal:
`hdiutil mount ~/Downloads/JavaForOSX.dmg`
`mkdir -p ~/Downloads/tmp/`
`pkgutil --expand "/Volumes/Java for macOS 2017-001/JavaForOSX.pkg" ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6/`
`hdiutil unmount "/Volumes/Java for macOS 2017-001/"`
`sed -i '' 's/return false/return true/g' ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6/Distribution`
`pkgutil --flatten ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6/ ~/Downloads/tmp/JavaSE6.pkg`
`rm -r ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6`
Run/double-click on `"JavaSE6.pkg"` file inside `~/Downloads/tmp/` folder.
End-of-TLDR

BEGIN:

"LEGACY JAVA" is older version of Java SE JRE/JDK, etc.

- Some apps specifically need to use very specific (old) version of Java SE JRE/JDK, etc.
  So user need to load those specific version, which is required by an App.
- One computer can have/use multiple versions of Java JRE/JDK, etc.
- Older Apple macOSX included Java. ( i think, upto Java SE 6 in upto macOSX High-Sierra 10.13 ).
  Then Apple macOSX stopped including any Java, so user had to load on their own.
- OBTAIN JAVA :  I suggest to use [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) based Java (OpenJDK based Java release includes JDK & JRE) from `https://OpenJDK.Java.net/` site (it is free for any Commercial usage & also free for any Personal usage & you're free to include JRE/JDK with your App, etc ) , use OpenJDK when a java-based App needs (latest) Java or Legacy-Java (not below Legacy-Java 6).
  To obtain Legacy-Java, we can also get it from 'Oracle' website ('Oracle' purchased 'Sun', & 'Sun' developed Java), but Java from 'Oracle' is free only for Personal usage, & also needs user to free-registration in website, it is not-free for Commercial usage, & not-free if you want to distribute JRE with your App, etc . If App needs older than Legacy-Java 6 (1.6), then we have to get it from 'Oracle' site, as OpenJDK does not have older than Legacy-Java 6 (1.6).
  By the way, [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/)'s macOS optimized Java binary-files (and src-code) are available for Java 9 (1.9) & above, in OpenJDK [archive-site](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) . And OpenJDK 6([1.6](https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/)), 7([1.7](https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/)), 8([1.8](https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/)) are available as Src-code form only, So dev/user have to compile Src-code to get macOS optimized binary for OpenJDK 6, 7 or 8.
  So its easier+better that, for last binary+src of Legacy-Java 6 (1.6) (Java JRE+JDK 6 (1.6)) that is optimized for macOS, we should use Apple website: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US ( `"JavaForOSX.dmg"` (en_US) file, 51.1MB, md5:5bc4ef2d2115f8b35bc6c0bd792477d5, sha1:10687ebc3d0965bd0fcbad600ae48ee84e0eff04. )

in macOSX Catalina (or in macOS-XI/11/X1 after it) download it in default `~/Downloads/` folder.

PROBLEM : if you try to install Legacy-Java **package/pkg/PKG** in macOSX ( i think in macOSX Mojave or macOSX after it ) you will receive various ERRORS from macOSX installer `"This package is incompatible..."` , it will STOP INSTALLING, etc, As it is very old, etc.

SOLUTION :  So you will have to do some further modification(s) on `pkg` installer file on your own with below instructions, ( Do not download/use someone else's modified `pkg` file, as it may have unwanted components in it ).
Part of these below instructions are adopted from [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/java-6-runtime-legacy-version-for-macos-catalina.2195954/)-site user [bogdanw](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/java-6-runtime-legacy-version-for-macos-catalina.2195954/post-27855520) (THANK YOU, bogdanw) , which are then further modified by me as original instructions were not working properly for me.

Note:

- in below `'cmd:'` word is indicating a command is given after it, to type in the `Terminal` utility. Do not type/use the `'cmd:'` word itself when you type/copy a command.
- when you see `'<YourUserName>'` then change it to your actual macOS user name , and do not use the '<' or '>' symbols. An example: the `~/Downloads` folder means `/Users/<YourUserName>/Downloads` folder . The '`~`' is short form of `/Users/<YourUserName>` folder aka your HOME folder . Folder = Directory.

Follow below INSTRUCTIONS:

- in `Finder`, double-click/tap on that Legacy-Java `"JavaForOSX.dmg"` file , macOS HDIutil will mount/load the DMG archive file & in Finder you will see a new mount point (aka, new drive) `"Java for macOS 2017-001"` has appeared, & it has a file `"JavaForOSX.pkg"` inside it.
  if you prefer to do this via Terminal:
  `cmd:  hdiutil mount ~/Downloads/JavaForOSX.dmg`
- start `"System Preferences"` , in macOSX Catalina (or Mojave or macOSX after it) goto `"Security & Privacy"` > `"Privacy"` > `"Full Disk Access"` > click on `"+"` to add a new tool/app > File-browser window will appear, but it will not show HIDDEN files, so press `[Cmd]+[Shift]+[.]` 3-buttons together to Show Hidden Files. Browse into `/usr/sbin/` folder, find the `"pkgutil"` binary file, select/open it, and make sure "pkgutil" in list has a tick-mark/check-mark next to it, so it gets full disk access.
- `"Terminal"` utility need to be given either full-disk-access Or at-least access to these folders: `"Downloads folder"`, `"Removable Volumes"` . Once you do something (i.e: run a command like this in Terminal: `cmd:  echo "1" > ~/Downloads/test.txt` ) inside Downloads folder from Terminal, then macOS will ask you if you want to allow Terminal to access Downloads folder, allow that, (a privileged user & user's Password is needed to approve/allow that).
- open `"Terminal"` utility (if not yet open), Type in below COMMAND(s):
  `cmd:  mkdir -p ~/Downloads/tmp/`
  `cmd:  pkgutil --expand "/Volumes/Java for macOS 2017-001/JavaForOSX.pkg" ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6/`
  ( if you see error: `"Error encountered while creating /Users/<YourUserName>/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6/. Error 17: File exists"` , then delete the `"OSXJavaSE6"` folder (which is inside the `tmp` folder which is inside the `Downloads` folder), and run above `pkgutil` cmd again )
  `cmd:  hdiutil unmount "/Volumes/Java for macOS 2017-001/"`
  ( output: `"/Volumes/Java for macOS 2017-001/" unmounted successfully.` )
  `cmd:  sed -i '' 's/return false/return true/g' ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6/Distribution`
  `cmd:  pkgutil --flatten ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6/ ~/Downloads/tmp/JavaSE6.pkg`
- remove this folder & it's contents: `cmd:  rm -r ~/Downloads/tmp/OSXJavaSE6`
- double-click/tap on the newly created `"JavaSE6.pkg"` file, inside the `~/Downloads/tmp/` folder, to run it.
  It should start the Legacy-Java 6 installer, & should install without further errors, (when you provide a privileged user Password again, when macOS asks for it).
  after install, Installer program will ask you, if you want to delete the `pkg` file, do not delete, `Keep` it.

  - copy `~/Downloads/tmp/JavaSE6.pkg` file into `~/Downloads/` folder, in case later you decide to delete everything inside `~/Downloads/tmp/` folder:
    `cmd:  cp  ~/Downloads/tmp/JavaSE6.pkg  ~/Downloads/`

Remove full-disk-access permission from `"pkgutil"` if you will not do any more direct `pkg`-file modifications : just remove the tick/check mark from `"pkgutil"` for now, from here: System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access.

DONE.

OPTIONAL / EXTRA : Check existing JAVA installations:

`cmd:  /usr/libexec/java_home -V`
output of above cmd may look like below, (in my side it shows below info as those were my existing items when this answer was written):
`Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):`
    `14.0.1, x86_64:    "OpenJDK 14.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`
    `1.7.0_80, x86_64:  "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home`
    `1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64:  "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`
    `1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386:    "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`
( in above, the last line of output is showing the default JAVA location/version )

OPTIONAL / EXTRA : Setup Specific Java ENV-VAR (ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE) for specific Java-based App:

Find a solution thats suitable for your need/implementation:

- JAVA_HOME (10.6) - [What should I set JAVA_HOME environment variable on macOS X 10.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348842/)
- JAVA_HOME (10.9) - [How to set JAVA_HOME environment variable on Mac OS X 10.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/)
- JAVA_HOME (10.14) - [Where is JAVA_HOME on macOS Mojave (10.14) to Lion (10.7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588390/)
- JAVA_HOME - [How to set JAVA_HOME environment variable on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517507/)
- Setting ENV VAR on MacOS - [Setting environment variables on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/)
- Direct an App to use specific JAVA by changing app Info.plist - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202931/

(some Java-based App can find & use specific Java version (if pre-installed), without the need for ENV VARs setup by a shell/bash script, But some Java-based App needs ENV VARs set by shell script)

SETUP/USE SPECIFIC JAVA FOR A SPECIFIC JAVA-BASED APP:
in this way different Java-based App can use different Java . For this, we have to run a script file, & it will setup ENV VARs `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH`, etc only for that specific App, before running the app:
`cmd:  sb='#!/bin/bash' ; echo "$sb" > ~/java-based-APP-name.sh ; unset sb;`
edit the shell script file:
`cmd:  nano ~/java-based-APP-name.sh`

- 1st line must be `#!/bin/bash` to use it as "BASH" shell script, then add below 5-lines:
  `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.6);`
  `export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH";`
  `# $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar executableJarAppName.jar`
  `# $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp jarAppName.jar <full-path-of-main-class>`
  `"/Applications/java-based-APP-name.app/Contents/MacOS/java-based-APP-name"`
- Save `"~/java-based-APP-name.sh"` & exit out from `nano` . ( [Nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html) )
  ( Note: if a macOS app's name is `"My MacApp.app"`, then it must have an executable file with same name here: `"My MacApp.app/Contents/MacOS/My MacApp"` . So above example script is using that example executable )
- set executable permission (attribute bit) for the shell script:
  `cmd:  chmod +x ~/java-based-APP-name.sh`
- now you can RUN the App by using it's shell script `.sh` file, so that it can get the specific Java that it needs:
  `cmd:  ~/java-based-APP-name.sh`

Suppose you have a different (java-based) App2 that specifically needs Legacy Java 7 (1.7):

- obtain Legacy Java 7 (JDK, 1.7) binary (and src) from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase7-archive-downloads.html) site & install it . ( [OpenJDK](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) based Legacy Java 7 ([1.7](https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/)) src-code is available in OpenJDK.java.net site, for those, who want to compile it & build their own binary. )
  Copy-paste above `"java-based-APP-name.sh"` shell-script, & rename copied filename into: `"App2.sh"`, & Edit it: `cmd:  nano ~/App2.sh` , & change line-number 2nd & 6th, as shown below:
  `Line#2:  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.6);`
  `Line#6:  "/Applications/java-based-APP-name.app/Contents/MacOS/java-based-APP-name"`
  And change those/above two lines like below:
  `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.7);`
  `"/Applications/App2.app/Contents/MacOS/App2"`
  Save `~/App2.sh` & exit out of `nano`.
  And set 'execute' bit: `cmd:  chmod +x ~/App2.sh`
  Now you can run it: `cmd:  ~/App2.sh`

EXTRA INFO:
I was trying to run an old macOS app & the latest `Jitsi.app`.
Jitsi showed message that it needed Legacy-Java 6, but after installing Legacy-Java 6, i received such error:
`[JavaAppLauncher Error] CallStaticVoidMethod() threw an exception`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/java/sip/communicator/launcher/SIPCommunicator : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`
So i had to load Java 7 (1.7) for Jitsi (because, error-msg "51.0" points-to Java 7) . Jitsi can auto detect the needed Java version & use it, so no extra bash-script was needed for Jitsi, it ran fine.
For the old macOS app, i had to use Legacy-Java ( Java 6 (1.6) ) & a bash-script (shown above).

Comment: i've tried sporadically for months to fix this, and this is the method which worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I simply added to installation (requires a free account) the latest [jdk-8u251-macosx-x64.dmg](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html) JDK from Oracle and everything turned out fine.